# TFS 2012 configuration Access Denied: [User Name] needs the following permission(s) to perform this action: View collection-level information

Tags: tfs

Earlier it was working fine now its start giving below error on click of Security Tab after some unwanted change:
Error Message: Access Denied: Badal Kumar needs the following permission(s) to perform this action: View collection-level information

NB: This problem happening for Multitenant Team project

Result After executing the below command:

[C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 11.0\Tools>TFSSecurity /imx /collection://SRV:8080/tfs/defaultcollection n:elitewind\Badal]

Result:
Identity type: Windows user
   Logon name: ELITEWIND\Badal
 Display name: Badal Kumar

Member of 19 group(s):
  [A] [TEAM FOUNDATION]\Project Server Integration Service Accounts

e [A] [MultiTenant]\Project Valid Users

[A] [TEAM FOUNDATION]\SharePoint Web Application Services

[A] [DefaultCollection]\Project Collection Build Administrators

[G] BUILTIN\Administrators

[A] [TEAM FOUNDATION]\Team Foundation Proxy Service Accounts

[A] [MultiTenant]\Build Administrators

[A] [DefaultCollection]\Project Collection Proxy Service Accounts

[A] [DefaultCollection]\Project Collection Test Service Accounts

[A] [MultiTenant]\MultiTenant Team

[A] [MultiTenant]\Readers

a [A] [DefaultCollection]\Project Collection Administrators

[A] [MultiTenant]\Contributors

e [A] [DefaultCollection]\Project Collection Valid Users

s [A] [TEAM FOUNDATION]\Team Foundation Service Accounts

a [A] [MultiTenant]\Project Administrators

s [A] [DefaultCollection]\Project Collection Service Accounts

a [A] [TEAM FOUNDATION]\Team Foundation Administrators

[A] [DefaultCollection]\Project Collection Build Service Accounts

Done.

Answer (score 0):

One of those groups has View Collection-level Info set to deny. 
Open the Control panel, choose "Manage collection security and group membership", select the user and hover your mouse over the "View collection-level info" item. It should say "deny" and  a "Why?" should show up next to it.
That will tell you which Group the deny value is being inherited through.